# ACL view & edit two contact groups

Tags: drupal, groups, acl, roles

I'm running CiviCRM 4.6.9 (yes I'm late!) with Drupal 7.

I have two groups of contacts (regular, not smart groups) A and B. I need to allow a group of user to view and edit contacts in these 2 groups.

So I created a Drupal role, with "Access CiviCRM" and "Use ajax API" permissions (in Drupal), created my Drupal users, gave them my new Drupal role, then I created an ACL group and a role in CiviCRM, assigned this role to the Drupal role and finally added my privileged CiviCRM contacts in this group. Then I created 4 ACL to the role :

- edit contacts in group A
- view contacts in group A
- edit contacts in group B
- view contacts in group B

With only the first two ACLs its working fine, my new users can see and edit contacts in the A group.

When I add the 2 last ACLs, it seems that they "override" the first (group A), and when I try to list all contacts in A group (logged as my new user) I can only see contacts that belong to both group (A and B). I can view and edit all contacts in B group. So when I navigate to "Groups management", I have the correct number of contact for group A, but when I click on "Contacts" on group A line I get fewer contacts (only those who are in both groups).

I tried to create 2 Drupal roles / 2 CiviCRM ACL roles, one for each group (trying to separate ACL across 2 ACL groups), I had the same result.

Is there something I missed here ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I think my problem is related to this issue :

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-11230

Apparently it is still pending with no recent patch :(.